Advice on skimming
I am working on skimming over our bathroom that has painted walls. I have prepped the walls by scraping, sanding them, then wiped them down with TSP. I had started skimming in some small areas with diluted AP joint compound, but I noticed the mixture was getting small bubbles in it. These bubbles worked out as it dried, but now I am concerned about adhesion.
Is this enough prep to skim? Are the bubbles normal? Any other advice on skimming is welcome.

If you don't mind me asking, what is "AP"?

All purpose joint compund

Sanding is all that is needed with a good dusting to remove the loose dust. TSP is a great cleaner that is used for a lot of prep work, a good move too, as long as there is no residue.
Since you diluted the joint compound, that tells me you already used a mixer. Whether water is added or not, this is what is done to reduce the amount of air bubbles that are already in the mix.
Bubbles will occur even after mixing, it does reduce them. I find that wiping it out a few extra times help get rid of even more. That means putting on more than you need, then wiping it down. I do that as a rule any way.
If you are not done already, a tip I learned a while back is, do not attempt to do the whole surface at one time. Instead place ribbons of mud spaced about 6-8 inches apart, well tapered to the wall, using a 12" knife. After that dries, fill in the middles and the mud should have less lines in it to sand out. I also use a knife with a cambered edge, I bent it so it is curved slightly to build up using one side, or smoothing out without the corners dragging leaving lines using the other side.

You thinned the compound too much, and didnt rinse all the TSP.
